# Laravel Eloquent relationship return Trying to get property 'office_name' of non-object

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, eloquent

This is my Eloquent Relation -

```php
public function owner()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Owner::class, 'owner', 'owner_name');
}
```

And here when I access full object -

```
{{ $dealer->owner }}
```

I get the object

```
{
    "id": 11087,
    "office_name": "BHILWARA DTO ( RJ-6 )",
    "registration_number": "RJ06VS2840",
    "chasis_number": "MBLHAR076J4K00280",
    "owner": "GANESH LAL",
    "father_name": "KASTUR KUMAWAT",
    "address": "THALARAIPUR",
    "vehicle_class": "M-Cycle\/Scooter",
    "insurance_type": "COMPREHENSIVE",
    "insurance_company_name": "TATA AIG GENERAL INSURANCE CO. LTD.",
    "insurance_from": "2018-11-08",
    "insurance_up_to": "2019-11-07",
    "policy_number": "0189518728",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
}
```

but when I try to access single property from the object -

```
{{ $dealer->owner->office_name }}
```

I get error

> Trying to get property 'office_name' of non-object

Comment: My best guess is that the `$dealer` is in a foreach and one of them don't have an owner

Comment: what should I do then?

Comment: There might be a dealer that has a missing owner on the database.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to get the office_name from model array object without the `foreach` loop so that's you are getting the below.

Try this

```
@foreach($dealer->owner as $de)

{{ $de->office_name }}

@endforeach
```

Comment: hasOne relationship returns a model not a collection

Answer (score 0):

As per the laravel documentation here is the syntax of hasOne relationship,

```
return $this->hasOne(Phone::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

So in your case,

```
return $this->hasOne(Owner::class, 'owner', 'owner_name');
```

The third parameter is a local key column in the owner related table. But in your given object there isn't anything like owner_name, So the relationship should look like:

```
return $this->hasOne(Owner::class, 'owner', 'owner');
```